# How to provide alternative implementation of abstract interface in Scala?

Tags: scala, design-patterns

Here's the problem I'm facing:

I have an abstract trait `Toggles` which has an abstract method `isToggleEnabled(name: String)`.

What I want to have is to be able to have production environment trait `ProdToggles` with concrete implementation of `isToggleEnabled` and use it in the prod code but be able to provide overriding alternate trait `TestToggles` with new implementation `isToggleEnabled` when testing.

The reason is that production environment implementation uses System properties to store toggle names and their states, however in testing I would like to provide different implementation to store and read toggles, so that multiple tests could be run in parallel without affecting each other (as through System properties they would). What I came up with using cake pattern:

```
trait Toggleable {
  def isToggleEnabled(name: String): Boolean
}

trait ProdToggles extends Toggles with Toggleable {
  override def isToggleEnabled(name: String): Boolean = System.getProperty("name").toBoolean
}

trait TestToggles extends Toggles with Toggleable {
  val cache = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[String, Boolean]
  override def isToggleEnabled(name: String): Boolean = cache.getOrElse(name, false)
}

trait Toggles {
  this: Toggleable =>

  def isEnabled(name: String): Boolean = {
    isToggleEnabled(name)
  }
}

//—————IN PROD code—————

class Prod() {

  this: Toggles =>

  def doSomething(): Unit ={
    isEnabled("toggle.name")
  }
}

object Prod {
  def apply(): Prod = new Prod with ProdToggles
  def apply(testing: Boolean) = new Prod with TestToggles
}

//——————IN TEST code———————————
class Tests {
  val prod = Prod(true)
  prod.doSomething()
}
```

However, problem with that:

1. Breaks encapsulation and `Prod` instance could be misused as `Toggle` instance as you could do `(new Prod with ProdToggles).{isEnabled, isToggleEnabled, doSomething}`
2. Every `Prod` class mixin `Toggles` will need an `object` with `apply` factory to return custom instance for testing and for prod
3. Cake-pattern is an anti-pattern

Would you have any other approaches to go around this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what was the purpose of all those indirections. Also, what exactly do you want to test.
But, the general idea would be to have just **Traits** that define the API of your services, and default *(production)* implementations of those. If one implementation requires another service, it should depend on it.
For testing, you create mocks of the dependencies and test the service implementation.

For example:

```
// Toggleable.scala
trait Toggleable {
  def isToggleEnabled(name: String): Boolean
}

object Toggleable {
  final val impl: Toggleable =
    new Toggleable {
      override final def isToggleEnabled(name: String): Boolean =
        System.getProperty("name").toBoolea
    }
}

// Toggles.scala
trait Toggles {
  def isEnabled(name: String): Boolean =
}

object Toggles {
  final def impl(toggleable: Toggleable): Toggles =
    new Toggles {
      override final def isEnabled(name: String): Boolean =
        toggleable.isToggleEnabled(name)
    }
}

// Env.scala
trait Env {
  def doSomething(): Unit
}

object Env {
  final def prod(toggles: Toggles): Env =
    new Env {
      override final def doSomething(): Unit =
        println(toggles.isEnabled("toggle.name"))
    }
}

// Tests
object TestToggleable extends Toggleable {
  private val cache =
    scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[String, Boolean]

  override final def isToggleEnabled(name: String): Boolean =
    cache.getOrElse(name, false)
}


class Tests {
  val toggles = Toggles.impl(toggleable = TestToggleable)
  assert(toggles.isEnabled("balh") == false)

  val env = Env.prod(toggles)
  prod.doSomething() // Not sure how do you test an Unit.
}
```